# Is it possible to inherit interface generic types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I extend interface with saving its generic types without re-declaring them?

For example I have following code:

```js
interface Controller<
  Type extends Record<string, any>,
  IdType extends number | string,
  UpdateType extends Record<string, any>
> {
  get(id: IdType): Type;
  remove(id: IdType): Type;
  update(id: IdType, data: UpdateType): Type
}
```

And I need to create other interfaces that inherit the same generic types.
The way I am doing it right now is by re-declaring all this types, like this.

```js
interface VotableController<
  Type extends Record<string, any>,
  IdType extends number | string,
  UpdateType extends Record<string, any>
> extends Controller<Type, IdType, UpdateType>{
  vote(id: IdType): Type;
  unvote(id: IdType): Type;
}

inteface UserEditableController<
  Type extends Record<string, any>,
  IdType extends number | string,
  UpdateType extends Record<string, any>
> extends Omit<Controller<Type, IdType, UpdateType>, "update" | "remove"> {
  update(id: IdType, data: UpdateType, userId: number): Type;
  remove(id: IdType, userId: number): Type;
}
```

I want to know is it possible to somehow inherit types `Type`, `IdType` and `UpdateType`, without copy pasting them every time to new interface.

It would be good to do it like this, but it gives an error

```js
interface FooController extends Controller {
   foo(): Type
}
// Error: ts(2707) Generic type 'Controller<Type, IdType, UpdateType>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible and it is one of the reasons, why complex hierarchies with a lot of generics are hard to maintain

Comment: Not possible to inherit the type parameter list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically there is a way but it involves some boilerplate and you need to learn a library XD. Needless to say I can't recommend it as it is, unless you really repeat yourself a LOT.

I am working on automating a lot of this with type transformers so conceptually the idea is not bad. Only half-backed.

The idea is to take a side step to a realm which supports threading arguments through, then convert back to normal types.

The first step is to lift `Controller` into a free type (a type constructor which can be passed around without parameters):

```js
import { Type, Checked, A, B, C, apply } from 'free-types';
```

```js
interface $Controller extends Type {
  type: Controller<Checked<A, this>, B<this>, Checked<C, this>>
  constraints: [
    A: Record<string, any>,
    B: number | string,
    C: Record<string, any>
  ]
}
```

Once this is done, we can create a free type that inherits form it. This is where the value of all of this lies: we don't repeat ourselves any more:

```js
interface $VotableController extends $PassThrough<<$Controller> {
  type: this['super'] & Voting<this[A], this[B]>
}

type Voting<Type, IdType> = {
  vote(id: IdType): Type;
  unvote(id: IdType): Type;
}

// util to pass arguments through while making constraints bubble up
interface $PassThrough<<$T extends Type> extends Type {
  super: apply<$T, this['arguments']> // this['super'] comes from here
  constraints: $T['constraints']
}
```

The last step is to apply it with arguments. This is done with `apply`

```js
type OK = apply<$VotableController, [{foo: number}, number, {foo: string}]>
```

`apply` checks type constraints

```js
// @ts-expect-error: not [Record<string, any>, string | number, Record<string, any>]
type NotOK = apply<$VotableController, [1, 2, 3]>
//                                     ~~~~~~~~~
```

Example of use with a class:

```js
class Foo<
  Type extends Record<string, any>,
  IdType extends number | string,
  UpdateType extends Record<string, any>
> implements apply<$VotableController, [Type, IdType, UpdateType]> {
  constructor (private a: Type, private b: IdType, private c: UpdateType) {}
  get(id: IdType) { return this.a }
  remove(id: IdType) { return this.a }
  update(id: IdType, data: UpdateType) { return this.a }
  vote(id: IdType) { return this.a }
  unvote(id: IdType) { return this.a }
}
```

As for `UserEditableController`, if you want to keep using `Omit`, you can use `Flow` to compose free types and cook a `$ControllerOmitting` free type constructor

```js
import { Flow } from 'free-types';

type $ControllerOmitting<T extends PropertyKey> =
  Flow<[$Controller, $Omit<T>]>

interface $Omit<T extends PropertyKey> extends Type<1> {
  type: Omit<this[A], T>
}
```

It can then be used the same way

```js
interface $UserEditableController
  extends $PassThrough<$ControllerOmitting<'update' | 'remove'>> {
    type: this['super'] & Editable<this[A], this[B], this[C]>
}

type Editable<Type, IdType, UpdateType> = {
  update(id: IdType, data: UpdateType, userId: number): Type;
  remove(id: IdType, userId: number): Type;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQJ5gKYBo4GEAWGAxgNYYAmOAgjgEI644CGYYANqjgGJsQDucAL5wAZlAgg4AcjEYMAWhjoMAZykBuAFCbgAOxgYoIpkQx4I+8WzaGAPJrgplcDAA8Du8irgAlYtHJbFRgoPQBzZl1UAD4sBzgASXI0TBd3DE9vXQBXEAAjQzgAHzhg0N0I+IBVMHImAxSzNw8vX38oQLLwyJjNaMR4sIwYAApgcgAuROTlAEopxq1HKAwQCAA3DDHJ6cb5p0wluGza+q3xqaTGnDqYJima24w9heVNQW09AyMTMwASXAWEIQayFZoZVqNAaOJSYKaAywgmxQWwEYhkQI0OAwfDAFSxOC0Ww4vEEtGkCionAk-HReJECxlJhfFRTADa8UcVCmfgZHSCIW6cCYUVinMJUxy+UKJS6FTijkcuB57U6gvlwtF8QAuu9PvpDMZTHA-gA1CB3PI2BHA0FQNItbx-AAKTBUKmQ+HE2TC+FsAKBVmR-QQ8VhGCmNLZUhUJ0MUm1cAAZHBzTBwsTcSo2VRtdSs2zaNq6R9NOHUxaM9ddsp+gBeaFwdYW847K5zV6HeLZXTNgzbS4zTD7RZ6nQGn7Gl1uj1eiA+v1-ZAOiHeRr9cGZA5mUOOWOYKBTFjsVD+5D5vHRphQMK5DIwNTF+mMkLM-Ssk3IaMM3RMlkJvVywAeQAaTgBtjw4f00yYK0MBtINDBwNkEBECAIElXICigQQcClbCcFQ9CpjlMJBCfTQAHpKLgAABB95DcTAiBgRioHEQ84F0C04BzFU+TVcoIk1GI6BI9UwmKLisKQvB+ICAUhJ6aJtSkMtnAAOQtUDwOFVgoLNC1YOtQMkVktkAEYcAAJhwABmJ9qMVZyXNctz3OcgA-byfJ87QiDYGc4C4dD7EcKFN1aXkFNI5SFRrVJIqyGT7VlCT4seM4IvSLdov5WKRLpfpQHYVZ728SDT0My0TMRO1kOrdtMBwTKGmUYtGx-MpshY6A4BGMBQnWM5hU7bA4EG4BhoMOA8kHatJumswiAeU42uHRAPkcIZRguBKMFmRA4BWGBsigXRsSzAA6JghHiFY1k2Ad9sOpATrOi6aRuu7HBOJ5nqa8bbnuOBWueOYjve87Lrxb6tqbFsAaHA7IeGD6YZUOHu17RG9sB17jrR6Gvtuj5Sy+Q1fhNICQGAGBbGXJK4GdcQDyUECMBiFct0aWwLJDMNlCmGm6czS9cxwZAS20csAzq5ERZgdMKgZ7nWhZiA2dQDmuYbHh+FsNk5dtZEcD+RWGZUulx2+I1-iqFRDAAUXIOnjPg0y7XiJnp3dT1vV9f0ELMqBFeVsJbCkP6zikKSpAejYMCkaIBec8NIwLGM4ygBNkzgF23bgsXswljHCzzMvcCfUtywLmqMAZ5QcEBlq1vBzB60baP+zx5GbnqEGwerbJHagJJMOlKAR2UI4E6e3vh9H8fpMn6euxr5xQOs3TKv9B3ndd+vg-q3iiIwlfsNwi-ZLP8ShPI6IgA)

The documentation and a guide can be found on the github [repo](https://github.com/geoffreytools/free-types)